# Issue selecting and removing multiple apps from listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a listview that allows you to do multiple uninstallations of selected applications. I wrote this code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
                applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(adapter.getList().get(a), a);
            }
        } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            for(int b=0; b<adapter.getPositions().size(); b++) {
            items = adapter.getPositions().get(b);
            appInfoArrayList.remove(items);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

This code works but not quite. Let me explain, for example, if I select the app normal user (so they are not system apps) they are removed properly from the list. If I select ONLY app system they are not uninstalled then are not removed from the list. So far the operation is correct. The problem is when I select for example two app system app and two normal. In this case, the selected system apps are removed from the list. Why? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be exiting early.

It looks like you are looping through the items. If an exception occurs, you cancel out of the loop, then start another loop which empties the entire list.

Maybe putting the try catch inside the original for loop is the solution?

Like:

```
for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
    try {
        applicationInfo = getPackageManager().
             getApplicationInfo(adapter.getList().get(a), a);
    }
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        items = adapter.getPositions().get(a);
        appInfoArrayList.remove(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        a--;
    }

}
```